# Increase Performance in SwingWorkers doInBackground

Tags: java, swing

I have a class that extends SwingWorker and iterates a list of objects to create new objects inside the doInbackground method. The issue I have is, that the object instantiation for each newly generated Market object takes about 1 second due to its initialize method that is getting called in the constructor.

Is there any way to increase the performance of my doInbackground so that the loop and object creation runs in parallel?

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Market loader running task with ticker size; " + this.ticker.size());
    synchronized (markets) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ticker.size(); i++) {
            TickerStatistics t = this.ticker.get(i);
            markets.add(new Market(t.getSymbol(), this.interval));  //this takes aprox. 1 second everytime so it is all executed sequentially
            setProgress(100 * i / ticker.size());
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I also tried this approach now but the speed is very slow as well as it seems to be running sequentially too.

```
 protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Market loader running task with ticker size; " + this.ticker.size());
    List<CompletableFuture> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ticker.size(); i++) {
        TickerStatistics t = this.ticker.get(i);
        int count = i+1;
        futureList.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> markets.add(new Market(t.getSymbol(), interval))).thenAccept(progress -> setProgress(100 * count / ticker.size())));
        futureList.forEach(CompletableFuture::join);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `SwingWorker` is does not provide a ready-made way to make the background work execute in parallel. You'll have to do that yourself, and make sure `doInBackground` does not return until all "subtasks" are done.

Comment: what would be the best approach? CompletableFuture.runAsync and add and update the progress there? The progress might be done on execution cause runAsync is not returning. Wenn I use supplyAsync it seems to be executing in sequential order very slow.

Comment: Your attempt to use `CompletableFuture` is flawed. Every iteration you add a new one to your list, then immediately `join` on all existing futures. That's effectively sequential. You need to launch all tasks, _then_ wait. Also, make sure your code is thread-safe (e.g., adding to `markets`).

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a hint on how to launch all tasks and then wait?

Comment: In your current code, just move the calls to `join` after the loop. Note you may see decreasing progress if a task with a lower "count" finishes after a task with a higher "count". And make sure that `markets` can be added to by multiple concurrent threads or change your implementation so that adding to `markets` is only ever added to by one thread at a time.

Comment: I have wrapped the loop arround a syncronized(markets) block if that is what you mean. I dont see much of an performance improove logging putting the join after the loop, although it makes sense to put it after it for sure.

Comment: A `synchronized (markets)` around the loop won't do what you expect. The `Supplier` passed to `supplyAsync` is invoked asynchronously on a different thread (in the common `ForkJoinPool` in this case). That different thread is not synchronized on `markets`, so no mutual exclusion is taking place. As for performance improvements, you should see _some_ improvement if your computer has more than one processor. If you're seeing _zero_ improvement, then my guess is that something in your code makes the initialization sequential. A [mre] would be needed to say more.